# Proof - a | b and b | a then a = b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> For all integers a and b, if a | b and b | a, a = b.

Can something think of a proof?

I have done this:

**Proof:**

Suppose m and n are integers such that m|n and n|m, but n ≠ m.
Let m = 1 and n = -1

We know that $m|n$ implies $n = mk$  where $k$ is an integer

1 = -1(-1) where (-1) is integer, therefore, $m|n$ and $n|m$ implies $m = nl$  where $l$ is an integer

-1 = 1 (-1) where (-1) is integer, therefore, $n|m$

however, $m \neq n$ since $1 \neq -1$.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What about $a=1, b = -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. What we have is $a = \pm b$.

We have $a=k_1b$ because $b \mid a$ and $b= k_2a$ because $a \mid b$.

Multiplying gives $ab=k_1k_2ab$, thus $k_1k_2=1$. Therefore we have $k_1=k_2=1$ or $k_1=k_2=-1$. Thus $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Comment: oh thanks - so this is false. Spent so much time trying to prove it true. So, k1 and k2 are integers. so what about the counter example 1, and -1?

Comment: @Samim We have a=b or a=-b. Try to deduce this form the value of $k_1k_2$.

Comment: Proof: Suppose m and n are integers such that m|n and n|m, but n ≠ m.
Let m = 1 and n = -1

We know that m|n implies n = mk  where k is an integer

 1 = -1(-1) where (-1) is integer, therefore, m|n

and n|m implies m = nl   where l is an integer

 -1 = 1 (-1) where (-1) is integer, therefore, n|m

however, m ≠ n since 1 ≠ -1

Comment: @Samim You don't need contradiction; if $a = k_1b$ and $b = k_2a$ then by substituting you have that $b = k_2a = k_2(k_1 b) = k_2k_1b$, which shows that $k_2k_1 = 1$. Hence, since $k_1$ and $k_2$ are integers, there are only two possibilities for their simultaneous value...